# Java AES encryption similar to aesCryptoServiceProvider

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

Well I want to generate the AES key using java and mentioned is the specification based on ".NET" utility that need to follow while generating the key in JAVA program

Specification: "Generate AES key using AesCryptoServiceProvider with Mode = ECB, Padding = PKCS7, KeySize = 256 &
BlockSize = 128."

I researched a lot but didn't get similar things that can be used  in Java to generate the AES key.

Can anyone please guide me how to move ahead with the same to create the AES key with above specification mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

For an AES key either use random bytes obtained from a [CSPRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) or derive the key from a passphrase with [PBKFD2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2).

Do not use ECB mode in new work and update legacy work ASAP, it is not secure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin. Instead use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to be secret.

Notes:

The Java base implementation limits the key size to 128-bits (which is fully secure), in order to use a larger key you need to you have to use Java Cryptography Extension:
[Java 6 JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html), [Java 7 JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html), [Java 8  JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html)
(Thanks to [Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150978/robert) for the versions info and links!)

AES only has one block size: 128-bits.

For Java see the Documentation [Java Cryptography Architecture Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html) and in particular [The Cipher Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#Cipher).

Comment: Are you sure the linked Unlimited Strength policy files from Java 6 work in current JREs?

Comment: @Robert No but there is no reference to Java 6. The main point I was trying to make is that without the addition of Unlimited Strength capability only 128-bit keys are supported and that 128-bit keys are sufficiently long.

Comment: The link you posted points to the Unlimited Strength policy files for JRE 6. There is also a variant for [Java 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html) and [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html)

Comment: ECB may be bad, but the OP seems to have a requirement to use it to match up with a .net program on the other end?

Comment: @bmargulies True, added "new work" wording. The information about ECB is also for future readers, that is what SO is all about: future readers. We need to try and reduce new uses of ECB mode.